# Javascript create button and trigger onclick function on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm facing an issue , where the javascript is responsible to create the button then show it on HTML( Pop up box ).

Once it's created, i want the user to freely click a button to close it.
The workaround is by setting the `modal.style.style=display`
.

In the HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class='modal-header'>
  <span class='close'>&times;</span>
<div id ="sub" >

  </div>

</div>
```

I have a function to create a modal box upon getting success variable, i'm appending to the id `sub`.

```
div.innerHTML = 
"<div id=''><span class='close'><input type='image' id='vicious' onclick='clear()' style='width:100%;' border='0' src='images/DUK.png' ></span></div>"
```

When it shows on HTML, i want to trigger an onclick function to close this modal box.
Because everything is created by the javascript, so I think the issue it's not triggering any line.

I've tried creating an onclick function to trigger

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    function clear(){

        modal.style.display = "none";

    }
```

I've also tried

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var vicious = document.getElementById("vicious");

    vicious.onclick = function() {

        modal.style.display = "none";

    }
```

I'm out of idea, could someone guide me?
Thanks in advance.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/rusapudodo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I don't see **`myModal`** used anywhere! Check if you are setting the id of modal div properly.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary, a sec let me paste the full code.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary, i've updated it thanks.

Comment: using innerHTML to bind events.. such a sad time to live in

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary, yeap

Comment: @GottZ, bad move?

Comment: @FreedomPride well depending on your sourcecode and where this data is coming from you are throwing into innerHTML this might risk you to xss attacks. if you really want to go this route then at least use a template language like handlebars or jade or similar. otherwise you should use jquery's .html to set html contents and bind the events using dedicated event bindings. well its fine as long as you know what you are doing but lets just say: be careful when using innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, you can achieve hiding of modal as per below steps,

1. Remove binding of click event, `onclick='clear()'`. This is not needed.
2. Bind listener to the element with id as **vicious** using,

   ```
   $('#vicious').click(function() {
       $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   });
   ```

**Alternatively** try the following approach,

```
$("#vicious").on("click", function(e){
     $("#modal").modal("hide");
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Stop the event from bubbling up.

If you want to use vanilla javaScript onlt then include the following code after you set the inner html,

```
var btn = document.getElementById("vicious");
btn.onclick = function() {
    alert();
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: no luck, cause innerhtml failed to bind event. I've added this in the html page also no luck because my javascript is separate.

Comment: Add the piece of code in the javaScript file that you have kept separately

Comment: added a jsbin, if you click the small x button on top it will clear everything , but submit button with no image doesn't do so that's my issue.

Comment: okay.. let me see....  Although I don't see you using the piece of code that I provided.

Comment: this is the original one, i've tried your code putting at the below of the innerhtml, clicking the button never trigger anything . even at the html page.

Comment: that code has to be put in your javascript file. Have you included jQuery in your app?

Comment: in the html i've included , ` <script type="text/javascript"

    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: in js , var script = document.createElement('script');
 
script.src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

Comment: the jsbin you sent is mine O_o, nothing different.

Comment: @FreedomPride Working here, check this.. http://jsbin.com/faxuqatipe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: mate, i think.. i know what's the real issue.. thanks to you i realize it .. my last + div has no `;` to end it..that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class='modal-header'>
            <span class='close' onclick="close()">&times;</span>
            <div id="sub">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function close(){
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It wouldn't work, i need to give image the specific id to close it not the span.

Comment: Well if you want to close the modal, you don't need the id of the img, simply 
 add : `onclick="close()"` in your img.

Comment: added a jsbin to my post to know more info

Comment: Well you lost me now, maybe I did not get what your are trying to do. Why are you using an input to close your modal ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the selector inside the function:

```
function clear() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

EDIT: using your second technic:

```
div.innerHTML = ...;
var vicious = document.getElementById("vicious");
vicious.onclick = clear;
```

Comment: the second method not working, added a jsbin to my post

Comment: By the way nice use of the `&times;`, also tell me if my jsbin is working for you

Answer (score 0):

For disabling button, you can use the below code

```
$("#button0000000001").find("button").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Does the question ask about disabling the button?